# How to covert hummming into pitches?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, music

I am not sure if this question suits this site, but I want to convert humming into notes or relative values to analyse melodies, word of "Signal Processing" looks suit for this. I am planning to use Flash AS3, and [Tortoise and Hare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) for Cycle Detection. I need very simple script implementation. All I want is find notes more easily with my bass. Is that possible? Or is there any frameworks that already makes this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a Pitch Track for monophonic signal, you need track low pitches!

There is a wide range of algorithms to find Pitches in time domain (zero crossing, AMDF, YIN, MPM, ASDF, autocorrelation ....) or Frequency domain (shs, hps, cepstrum ....)

Each one of them possess advantages or disadvantages !

With the Pitch Track you can convert one frequency to note.

I never used Flash AS3 to DSP, one fast and easy way are the autocorrelation based algorithms.

Comment: Which languages or tools do you suggest? AS3 has a capability to rich microphone, I am not aware of any other languages, AS3 is all I have

Comment: Use what you know, I'm not expert in AS3, if you decide use Frequency domain algorithm get a fast FFT implementation like [code](https://code.google.com/p/fseq-flash/source/browse/trunk/src/gerrybeauregard/FFT.as) by Gerald T. Beauregard you can use it in real-time.

Visit the blog of author http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/ :-)

Comment: by your links I just noticed that JS has a capability create and manipulate audio! wow!!

Answer (score 1):

Pitch estimation of humming sounds will likely require more than a simple script implementation for reliable results.  If you look at the waveform of humming sounds with an oscilloscope, you will probably find that the periodic waveform is usually not a simple mapping function suitable for the tortoise and hare algorithm.

Comment: I just checked waves in Goldwave, yes they have not a unique forms, but they look very similar in every steps. Is all I need to do find wave ranges?